# How to Shuffle/Deal a deck of cards in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, war, shuffle

Hello everyone I am currently making a GUI. It is going to be the card game called war what I am trying to do is split the deck randomly between the user and the computer. I have made three arrays one for you computer and the full deck and I made a for loop with nothing in it because everything i tried didn't work. Any help would be appreciated

```
public class WarMultiScreen {

static int[] fullDeck = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,
        15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,
        32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48,
        49, 50, 51, 52 };
static int[] playerDeck; // the players deck
static int[] opponentDeck; // the computers deck

static String tMade = new String();
static int turnsMade = 0;
static int warsDeclared = 0;
private JFrame frmWarcardGame;
JPanel panelScreen1;
JPanel panelScreen2;
Random rand = new Random();
private JTextField textField;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;
private JTextField textField_3;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                WarMultiScreen window = new WarMultiScreen();
                window.frmWarcardGame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public WarMultiScreen() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frmWarcardGame = new JFrame();
    frmWarcardGame.setTitle("War (Card Game)");
    frmWarcardGame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frmWarcardGame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frmWarcardGame.getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    panelScreen1 = new JPanel();
    panelScreen1.setBackground(new Color(124, 252, 0));
    frmWarcardGame.getContentPane().add(panelScreen1,
            "name_180601670832760");
    panelScreen1.setLayout(null);

    panelScreen2 = new JPanel();
    panelScreen2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frmWarcardGame.getContentPane().add(panelScreen2,
            "name_180620303895729");
     // Loop for shuffling deck
    for (int i = 0; i <= fullDeck.length; i++) {


    }</i>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this question to shuffle your array:
[Random shuffling of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

Once it's shuffled, iterate over the array and deal the cards to the players arrays. Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < cards.size(); i++){
    if(i % 2 == 0){
        userDeck.add(i);
    } else{
        computerDeck.add(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: I did everything but when i go to do the .add it says will not work with int[]

Comment: Use an arraylist, not a raw array.